# Running a wpf Application on Tablet?

Tags: wpf, tablet

Will I be able to run my WPF application  on Windows based Tablet (or any other)? I am using SQL server compact, .NET Framework 3.5. What should I do to make it tablet compatible?

Looking forward to reply

Answer (score 0):

Tablets have two options, possibly three. Windows RT, Windows 8.1, Windows 8.1embedded.

RT is largely redundant now due to lack of uptake by hardware providers. Windows embedded is now an extended version of the normal OS, so if you can run on 8, you can run on embedded.

The easiest solution is to develop your app as a windows store application. That will install on all either via the store, or side loading. If RT is not your concern, and I wouldn't blame you, just write it as you would any other 8.1 windows application.

You've specifically mentioned SQL and .net 3.5. I'd strongly suggest minimising SQL requirements on the target workstation. I'd also put a strong case for moving to .net 4 at least. That is a given for store apps.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I can run the application on Windows 8 Desktop. Does it mean it should run on Windows 8 Tablet? I don't have any Web Service written. The database calls are sent directly to the SQL Server Compact. Is it possible to port the .sdf to tablet and run the application on Windows 8 Tablet as it does in Windows 8 Desktop?

Comment: A lot of tablet manufacturers are making tablets with Windows 8.1 now. RT seems to be a non-starter. If your tablet is running windows 8.1 then you can install software on there as though it were a desktop - that said, if your tablet is running an ARM core - you will need software that has been compiled for it. So SQL may present a challenge. Compatibility is governed by many things so being clear with your customer is key.